# Inserting HTML formatted (not a resource) string in android TextView

Tags: android, html

I need to plug an HTML formatted string into a `TextView`. I'm retrieving the text from a database and when I insert it using this code

```
WebView webview = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
text = "<html><body>" + {text retrieved form database} + "</body></html>"
webview.loadData(text, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

It works but this code

```
 TextView output = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.simple_text);
 output.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

strips out all HTML formatting.

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: You wanna show html text in your web view is something i understand but why don't you just show your `{text retrieved form database}` directly in your text view. You can customize it within the text view itself like Bold, italics etc...

Comment: the text string contains <li> tags which am now realizing is not supported

Answer (score 0):

Start by getting rid of the `<html><body>` and `</body></html>` parts, as `Html.fromHtml()` does not use them.

Then, limit your HTML to [use tags that are supported by `Html.fromHtml()`](http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html).